# Visibility in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, visibility

I'm trying to create a page with a menu which has a different visibility for different users. I have 3 users: Users, Moderators and admins. Could somebody help me with this issue. Here is my code:

```
 echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Acties', 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->getIdentity('user')],
        ['label' => 'Maak afbeeldingen aan', 'url' => ['create'], 'icon' => 'file', 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->getIdentity('moderator')],
        ['label' => 'Beheer afbeeldingen', 'url' => ['admin'], 'icon' => 'list-alt', 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->getIdentity('admin')],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visible option is boolean. Defaults to true.

show this [Menu widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-menu.html#$items-detail)

also show the [getIdentity()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#getIdentity%28%29-detail)

try below code

```
echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => [
      ['label' => 'Acties', 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->getIdentity('user') ? true : false],
      ['label' => 'Maak afbeeldingen aan', 'url' => ['create'], 'icon' => 'file', 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->getIdentity('moderator') ? true : false],
      ['label' => 'Beheer afbeeldingen', 'url' => ['admin'], 'icon' => 'list-alt', 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->getIdentity('admin') ? true : false],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to right if condition example:

```
if(Yii::$app->user->getIdentity('moderator')){

 echo Menu::widget([
'items' => [

    ['label' => 'Maak afbeeldingen aan', 'url' => ['create'], 'icon' => 'file'],

],
]);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I already thought of that, but than I get 3 if statements and I want to keep my code as short as possible.